# Transfer time and procedure at New Delhi

Tags: air-travel, india

I am booking a trip to Dehradun from Dubai, via New Delhi.

My incoming flight will be on Emirates, and the domestic flight will be on whichever airline is most convenient.

My questions are:

1. According to the agent, I will need to clear immigration at Delhi and collect my checked-in baggage and then go to the domestic terminal and check in for the flight to Dehradun. Is this correct ?
2. How much time should I leave between the scheduled arrival and departure times at Delhi (both for arriving and departing India).

Comment: "1. According to somebody whose job it is to know about X, I should do X. Random strangers on the internet, is this true?"

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm not sure if this is always a good argument. Due to the reputation and badge system here,  TSE users aren't random. For example: Let's say I was from a developing country and trying to get a visa to the UK. A local immigration  lawyer has told me one thing. If I got an answer from someone like Gayot Fow here,  for example,  that would perhaps be more relevant than what the local lawyer told me. Perhaps not a fair comparison to this particular question,  but just saying.

Comment: @DavidRicherby travel agents, in my experience, know very little about X, they are all about the $$$. 2 different people in the same high street agency gave me completely conflicting advice. I'd much rather hear from hi-rep users on SE.

Answer (score 1):

New Delhi airport has two terminal buildings. The new one houses "Terminal 3 (T3)", the remaining are in the old terminal. Emirates will most likely land at T3. For your domestic leg (Delhi-Dehradun), the terminal depends on the airline. Air India, Vistara and Jet Airways use T3, the remaining use the old terminals.

There is a shuttle bus between the two terminals, and a metro rail link is under construction as well, but I have no up to date info on these.

For less hassle pick one of these. If you book star alliance, you can take an Air India flight for DEL-DED. Jet has codeshares with Etihad.

Comment: To whomever downvoted this, please consider leaving a comment.

Comment: absurd to downvote this